# Type to use to set Attributes in an ASP.NET Control?

Tags: c#

I am trying to add an attribute to a web page control.

```
TextBox txt=new TextBox();
txt.Attributes["Foo"]="Bar"
```

I need to put this in a method, but my problems is that I do not know what kind of element I will be sending to it - maybe an input maybe a select.  In essence I need this method below, but what is `oControl`?  In VB I used to just call it an `object`.

```
protected void SetAttrib(oControl){
    oControl.Attributes["Foo"]="Bar"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want [`WebControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx):

```
protected void SetAttrib(WebControl oControl){
    oControl.Attributes["Foo"]="Bar"
}
```

Comment: Beaten by two minutes. Again.

Answer (score 2):

WebControl

Comment: Control doesn't have an Attributes property.

Comment: Control class doesn't have Attributes property

Comment: Don't make me open Reflection!  I'm trying to be lazy here :)

WebControl has an Attributes property.

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter of a type that your webcontrols all inherit from.  Otherwise you could make it of type object and cast.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebControl class.

```
protected void SetAttrib( WebControl oControl, string bar )
{
     oControl.Attributes["Foo"] = bar;
}
```